# Complex .reduce to filter an array

Tags: reduce

so I'm trying to write a fancy reduce function (i could loop, but ...). Would love help on this -

The initial `items` array:

```
const items = [
  {'labels': ['a'], 'team': "infra"}, 
  {'labels': [], 'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': [], 'team': "InfraNew"},
  {'labels': ['new'], 'team': "infrastructure org"}, 
  {'labels': ['aaa'],'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': [], 'team': "Infra 1"},
  {'labels': ['b'],'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': ['a'],'team': "DT"},
  {'labels': ['c'], 'team': "DT"},
  {'labels': ['c', 'b'], 'team': null}
]
```

and the `filters` object.

```
const filters = {
  team: ['infra', 'DT'],
  labels: ['a', 'b']
}
```

The goal is to get `results` array of items, with labels within the filtered teams. (So if teams don't have matching labels, they should be excluded).

```
const results = [
  {'labels': ['a'],'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': ['b'],'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': ['a'],'team': "DT"},
]
```

This is what I have, but can't seem to get the conditioning correctly.

```
function filtering(res, el) {
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(filters).length; i++) {
    const key = Object.keys(filters)[i];
    let filterArray = filters[key];
    const elementValue = el[key];
    if (!elementValue) return res;
    if (key === 'labels') {
      if (elementValue.length === 0) return res;
      elementValue.map(elementValueItem => {
        if (filterArray.indexOf(elementValueItem) < 0) {
            return res
        }
      })
    } else if (filterArray.indexOf(elementValue) < 0) {
      return res;
    }
  }
  res.push(el);
  return res;
}

var results = items.reduce(filtering, [])
console.log(results)
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amnamka/sgy2j078/)

Answer (score 0):

It would greatly simplify your conditions if you thought about this problem in terms of `Array.prototype.filter`. I've done that for you below

```js
const items = [
  {'labels': ['a'], 'team': "infra"}, 
  {'labels': [], 'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': [], 'team': "InfraNew"},
  {'labels': ['new'], 'team': "infrastructure org"}, 
  {'labels': ['aaa'],'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': [], 'team': "Infra 1"},
  {'labels': ['b'],'team': "infra"},
  {'labels': ['a'],'team': "DT"},
  {'labels': ['c'], 'team': "DT"},
  {'labels': ['c', 'b'], 'team': null},
]

const filters = {
  team: ['infra', 'DT'],
  labels: ['a', 'b'],
}

const shouldKeep = item => {
  if (!filters.team.includes(item.team)) {
return false
  }
  if (item.labels.length === 0) {
return false
  }
  for (const label of item.labels) {
if (!filters.labels.includes(label)) {
  return false
}
  }
  return true
}

console.log(
  items.filter(shouldKeep)
)
```

Comment: Thank you richytong for your suggestion, it looks clean! I should have noted, my goal is to make it scalable, so I plan to remove any reference to `results` keys. Right now I have a check for `labels`.